# Error - Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled (ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Server space got full and after that got this error while starting mysql server

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit cron.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21001 and the job result is done.
Jun 05 12:49:38 server-instance systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 21.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 05 12:49:38 server-instance systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21002 and the job result is done.
Jun 05 12:49:38 server-instance systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 21002.
```

service mysql restart

i expect that mysql server get start running but not working.

Comment: What is the error message? any logs from /var/log/mysql?

Comment: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Insufficient for troubleshooting. Possible causes: configuration error, application conflict. Check /var/log/mysql or journalctl -xe for hints. Additional commands for more info: systemctl status mysql -l (is it stopped? try starting and checking logs), ps aux | grep [m]ysql (find mysql), netstat -tupln | grep 3306 (any port listening on 3306?).